# What is the most ‘understandable’ way to order sparkling water in German?

Tags: single-word-request, colloquial

I’ve heard of people saying *Mineralwasser*; should it automatically be understood as sparking water? 
Also, I heard (some) people saying *Wasser mit Gas* or *Gaswasser*, however, I don’t think I was always understood correctly.
So, what should I say, if I want to be almost always understood that I would like to order sparkling (carbonated) water?

Comment: Are you sure "Wasser mit Gas" and "Gaswasser" weren't actually "Wasser im Glas" and "[ein] Glas Wasser"?

Comment: My own experience with this was in the restaurant car on a train in Austria. In my very rusty German I asked the guy behind the counter for "Zwei Cola und ein Mineralwasser, bitte". Without missing a beat, he said in perfect English, "still or sparkling?" :D

Comment: You've just started the war of the regional variations of German :-) Looks like "mit Gas" is very divisive, with some saying "nobody in their right mind would say that" while Swiss people say it all the time...

Comment: @jcaron I mean… can we _really_ be sure that the Swiss are in their right minds?

Comment: It's a different language, but in Spanish it's fine to call it agua con gas and when it goes flat you just say it's sin gas.

Comment: @Tom: Seems somewhat irrelevant, as different languages use similar-sounding words in different ways. Note, for instance, that to an American, "gas" also denotes petrol used to fuel a vehicle. In German, in contrast, when we say a vehicle runs on "Gas", it does specifically *not* use conventional petrol, but natural gas. Likewise, at least regionally, "Gas" in general is colloquially understood as something used to heat your house or run a stove, but not something you'd want to ingest.

Comment: The use of 'gas' in American English to indicate petrol is an ill-educated misnomer and not comparable to my comment, I don't really care if they call it gas.

Comment: @Tom: It's comparable in that it is a convention from an entirely different language. What is or is not usual in Spanish has little to no bearing on what is or is not usual in (some variants of) German. That is, unless you can show that that particular convention from Spanish has somehow found its way into German.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are so many ways to express this and so many degrees and notions of what makes a sparkling water sparkling. When I first used the term "mit Gas" in German it was a humorous copy of how to express it during the vacation I had before (Spanish- "con gas"). Maybe the term "mit Gas" generally was imported into German, because "Gas" is usually not used for "Kohlensäure" (CO2) alone, but also for combustibles like propane, etc. (valid until correction ...)

The most understandable way in genuine German and my suggestion to express the order would be "Wasser mit Kohlensäure". Other expressions like e.g. "Sprudelwasser" are imaginable.

Comment: I've seen clauses in menus stating "An order of mineral water without further specification defaults to [default] if not explicitly stated otherwise" :-)

Comment: I think many bottles I saw in Austria used "prickelnd" on the label. Rather obvious to me as a Dutch native speaker.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje: könnte das in der Community-Wiki-Antwort mit erfasst werden? https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58077/36160

Comment: In Austria, the term "Sodawasser" is common. Be careful with "Mineralwasser", as it doesn't necessitate sparkling water.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Sure, done. It's just something I remembered from my many ski-trips.

Comment: @MechMK1 _Sodawasser_ is equivalent to _soda water_ in English (and seemingly equally dialectal). To any German speakers travelling north of the German border, it’s a false friend, though: Danish _sodavand_ refers to fizzy drinks (Sprite, Fanta, Coke), but not sparkling water which, rather bizarrely, is called _danskvand_ (‘Danish water’).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I believe in the US, "soda" also refers to carbonated drinks in general.

Comment: @MechMK1 In some dialects, yes; in others, no. Fizzy drinks in English is a dialectal mess. Actually, I think they’re a dialectal mess in quite a few languages. (And oddly, even in places where _soda_ is any carbonated drink, _soda water_ would still be understood to mean carbonated water specifically. Though I don’t think it would be used actively anywhere that also uses _soda_ on its own.)

Comment: Also in Spanish when it goes flat you just call it sin gas.

Comment: «Sprudelwasser» might not be readily understandable in Switzerland. I guess the word is a teutonism, that is, not used in Austria or Switzerland, but only in (parts of) Germany.

Comment: @a_donda: But maybe you could add at least that it is “in Germany” where the word «Sprudel» is used, as you have admitted yourself. Also, there are regions in Germany where «Sprudel» means ‘lemonade’, see [Die Getränke-Studie Teil 3: Zitronenlimonade](https://kristianmitk.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/die-getranke-studie-teil-3-zitronenlimonade/).

Comment: @a_donda: I understand your point. In spite of your point, your post mentions «Sprudelwasser», which is an example of “regional/local/personal specialities and preferences”. Why do you give this particular example of “regional/local/personal specialities and preferences” precedence over all others? Would it not be more consistent if you would really just “refer to the other answers”, like you intend to?

Comment: @mach: You're interpreting too much. My intention was to give a simple and concise answer. The other answers were posted after mine and some got my upvote. I only posted one example because, and i say that again, my intention was to keep it simple and on the point.

Comment: @a_donda: I am making two suggestions for improvement so your answer conforms better to your intention of simplicity or conciseness: 1. Make your answer even simpler by deleting the misleading final sentence. 2. Make your answer even more concise by improving the final sentence so it no longer is misleading: “Regional expressions like e.g. "Sprudelwasser" are imaginable.” I do not understand why you do not want to improve your answer.

Answer (score 33):

In Germany, *Mineralwasser* typically refers to carbonated sparkling water. Many people, including me, who were raised in Eastern Germany, would call all carbonated sparkling waters [*Selters*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selterswasser), even though *Selterswasser* is a brand of a particular water from a mineral spring in the [Taunus region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selters_(Taunus)).

If only water is mentioned, you can specify, whether it should be sparkling or not, by saying something like:

> Wasser mit / ohne …
>
> - … Sprudel
> - … Kohlensäure

Water that does not sparkle is also called

> stilles Wasser

For me, the specification *… mit / ohne Gas* sounds weird. It may be a direct translation from the English *with / without gas* or the Spanish *con / sin gas*. I have only heard this from non-native fellow students and colleagues.

Nowadays, there are also water bottles with the imprint

> Wasser medium

This is sparkling water that sparkles less than typical sparkling water.

Comment: And I thought "mit Gas" is a taken from Spanish :)

Comment: Klar, alles möglich.

Comment: Sparkling water might also be "Tafelwasser" (factory bottled tap water, basically). The defining characteristic of "Mineralwasser" is not the sparkle, but that it has minerals in it. However the only people who care about this are people who check food labels, I think in common parlance "Mineralwasser" and carbonated water are pretty much equivalent.

Comment: +1, just one remark: At least for me, living in southern Germany, "Wasser mit Sprudel" sounds a bit weird.  Here people would just say "Sprudel".

Comment: Not just spanish, but also italian and french use words that translate into German with "Gas" or "mit Gas versetzt", however, neither is used in German.

Comment: @rexkogitans, I hope you will appreciate that I will not list all relevant languages in my answer. ;-)

Comment: ["Mit/ohne Gas" ist absolut gängig in der Schweiz.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22wasser+mit+gas%22+site%3Ach&t=ffsb&ia=web)

Comment: @StephanKolassa, von den ersten 10 gelisteten Seiten, auf denen die Kombination *Wasser mit Gas* vorkommt, geht es in nur 3 tatsächlich um Mineralwasser. Der Rest beschäftigt sich mit Sanitär, Erdgas, Gashydraten usw. Und von den 3 relevanten haben wiederum 2 eklatante Schreibfehler, sodass man davon ausgehen muss, dass dort sprachliche Aspekte eine untergeordnete Rolle spielen. Das genügt mir nicht als Indiz für *absolute Gängigkeit*. Davon abgesehen habe ich den relevanten Absatz mit den Worten *Für mich ...* eingeleitet.

Comment: Naja, ich arbeite seit 16 Jahren in der Schweiz, und wenn ich im Restaurant "ein Mineral" bestelle (Betonung auf dem i!), dann werde ich gefragt "mit Gas?", und die Bedienungen sind sicher keine *non-native*s. Das ist täglicher Gebrauch, der sich im WWW möglicherweise nicht niederschlägt.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, ich verstehe. Ich wollte auch nicht anzweifeln, dass es so ist. Nur den *Beweislink* halte ich für ungeeignet. Wollen Sie Ihren Vorschlag zum Community Wiki hinzufügen, das hier auch eine Antwort hat?

Comment: @StephanKolassa: könnte das unter https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58077/36160 mit erfasst werden? (community wiki, Link zu Björn Friedrichs Vorschlag)

Comment: @StephanKolassa Seems like a swiss speciality then. Never heard that by any native German and my experiences cover quite a few areas of Germany. Though I agree most would likely understand what you mean.

Comment: FWIW, "Seltzer" would be intelligible to some in the US, although I don't hear it often. Apparently, [the English term derives from the German town Selters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonated_water#Etymology).

Comment: @StephanKolassa gerade im Servicebereich in der Schweiz arbeiten viele Zuwanderer. Als Schweizer würde ich niemals "mit Gas" sagen; kurioserweise hatte ich diesen Ausdruck immer mit Deutschen assoziiert, was sich in dieser Debatte klar als falsch erweist.

Comment: add: "Leitungswasser" for tap water and "Sodawasser" is almost archaic, but works too.

Answer (score 15):

### Collection of regional usage

For sparkling water there are various terms in German, and the common use in everyday life varies considerably in the various regions of the German speaking part of the world.

Therefore I offer here a community Wiki to collect the popular usage.

Think of how you would most shortly and clearly tell a waitress that you would like to have a glass of sparkling water, and don't forget to state your region.

- **North Rhine-Westphalia:** einen Sprudel
- **Swabia:** Saurer Sprudel / einen sauren Sprudel bitte
- **Mecklenburg-Vorpommern:** ein(e) [Selter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selterswasser), Selters
- **Brandenburg:** Selter, Selters
- **Switzerland**:

  - ein Mineralwasser mit Kohlensäure (formal)
  - ein Mineralwasser mit Gas
  - ein [Henniez](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henniez_(Mineralwasser))
  - ein Blöterliwasser (informal, dialectal)
  - ein Chrüseliwasser (informal, dialectal)
- **Austria:**

  - ein prickelndes Mineralwasser
  - ein Sodawasser (if you don't care about minerals)
- **Schleswig-Holstein:** ein Mineralwasser
- **Berlin:** at restaurant: Mineralwasser (in private Selter(s) can also be heard)

Comment: Yep, a nice list. I grew up at the banks of the river Lahn, Selters lies just upstream. And I've lived >30 years in south-western Germany and there I rarely heard "Selters" as an order for sparkling water. As you say, "saurer Sprudel" is the local expression there.

Comment: As a Swiss, I would not say "ein Mineral mit Gas". I would use the word Kohlensäure. Also another word would be "Blöterliwasser", though that I would not use to order at a restaurant.

Comment: Sprudel will most certainly also work in Rhineland Palatine, Saarland and likely Baden Württemberg.

Comment: Definitely will in Baden Württemberg, yes. Not all of it is swabian, but enough ;)

Comment: In Austria, I would recommend "Mineralwasser" or "Sodawasser". While "prickeld" is the correct description for sparkling water, it is used as a distinction between "prickelnd" (lots of gas), "mild" (a bit of gas) and "still" (no gas, usually for mineral water)

Comment: Not a native speaker, but in the Black Forest I ordered "Mineralwasser" expecting it to be still and it was sparkling - when I asked the waiter how I should have ordered still water he explained I should have said "nicht prickelnd" or "ohne Gas".

Comment: *Saurer* Sprudel? To my knowledge, here in Baden-Württemberg that denotes a Sprudel that has some lemon taste added to it, which is how ot becomes "sauer". That is, "saurer Sprudel" = "Zitronensprudel".

Comment: @NateMS I agree about "Kohlensäure". I tend to use "Blöterliwasser" primarily for sugared sodas.

Answer (score 11):

In Germany, sparkling water is pretty much ubiquitous. I personally dislike all sparkling beverages and I found out that if I just ordered water (*Wasser*) it would be sparkling water. I would almost go as far as saying that any order for simply water will get you sparkling water but that will probably be disproved by that one single restaurant sitting right on a non-sparkling mineral water fountain locally prized for its tasty water which will interpret *Wasser* as non-sparkling water. However, in 99.9 % of cases you will get sparkling water when simply ordering water.

If you want to make it absolutely unambiguously clear that you want the sparkling type, your options are:

- *Sprudel* or *Selters* – these two brands are understood all over the country as referring to a generic sparkling water. I tend to connect *Selters* more with my relatives from Berlin while *Sprudel* seems to be more common in most parts of former West Germany (it is often the case that there is an East/West divide with genericised brand names although it is not as common to see West Berlin following the East German name).
- *Wasser mit Kohlensäure* – the long and fully correct way of saying it. But, I would probably suggest sticking to *Wasser* until asked whether you want it with or without.

I advise against using *Wasser mit Gas*. It will most likely be understood but in my humble opinion it is not the most idiomatic way of expressing sparkling water. *Gaswasser* does not work. In fact, reading it my brain first associated it with *Gas/Wasser/Scheiße*, a tongue-in-cheek generic name for any municipal utility supplier and waste remover (water and gas supply, sewage removal).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer,  based on my experience growing up in Germany 1973-2002

Comment: To complete this answer: Explicitely asking for non-sparkling water can be done with "Wasser ohne Kohlensäure", "stilles Wasser" -- or if you don't even care for the minerals: "Leitungswasser" (tap water -- which, in germany, is as clean and drinkable as bottled water. Only the local calcium level is responsible for different tap water taste in different regions.)

Comment: as a (southwestern - might vary based on the tribe of germans you're interacting with :P) german, I'm upvoting this one. "Sprudel" will get you what you want. Some people will call it "saurer Sprudel", not because it's actually sour but to differentiate it from "süßer Sprudel" (which would be lemonade)

Comment: Came here to say this.... just order water. You will never get tap water and so it's never free, but I wouldn't expect to ever get water without carbonation without being asked

Comment: Is "Sprudel" really a brand name? I thought it was a generic (although maybe colloquial) term to begin with.

Comment: @orithena You can easily get tap water in Austria, but in Germany it's trickier. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/98425/56257 (and other answers to that question) for  the details.

Comment: @orithena I have received mildly carbonated water rather than still water at least once when ordering *stilles Wasser* so I have removed that option from my vocabulary. I also think I remember one brand of bottled water calling their mildly carbonated water *still* but unfortunately over a decade ago.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I’m not sure about what that linked answer says, it doesn’t fully match my past experience. Aside from the number of times I saw a waitor or waitress filling my glass right at the tap, most places I have been to will charge an *Apfelschorle mit Leitungswasser* as a small apple juice or not charge tap water at all if you ordered a meal to go with it. If they’re actually opening a bottle that cost them money, it wouldn’t make sense not to bill the customer. (cont.)

Comment: Furthermore, there are not that many brands of bottled still water available and due to the very low demand not that many restaurants will keep it in stock. Places that serve San Pellegrino sparkling water will probably have San Pellegrino still water, for example, but if their sparkling water is Adelholzner or Frankenbrunnen those just don’t come with a still version of the brand afaik. So they wouldn’t even have a bottle of still water to open and bill the customer.

Answer (score 11):

I'm from Germany and while I guess most people would understand "Wasser mit Gas", it definitely sounds very odd to a native German speaking person.

Actually, water with gas is the default in Germany. I myself usually just order "ein Wasser bitte". 99.99% of the time it will default to water with gas or you will be asked whether you want it with gas ("mit Kohlensäure").

If you want to make absolutely sure, just order "ein Wasser mit Kohlensäure".
You can also say "ein Mineralwasser", which (similarly to "ein Wasser") will default to water with gas.

Because of these defaults, an order for water without gas must be different: Make sure to say e.g. "ein stilles Wasser" / "ein Wasser ohne Kohlensäure".

Answer (score 8):

For utmost brevity, you might say "mit", and hope to be understood, at least if asked "mit oder ohne?"

Otherwise, the other answers apply. *Kohlensäure* would be my first guess. *Sprudel* is well acceptable. The bottle I'm looking at right now says *classic*, which is not even German, but shows a trend which I wouldn't have guessed existed, if it wasn't mentioned in a comment. *Gas* is outright wrong. *Stilles* doesn't help here, insofar the opposite *nicht still, kein Stilles* is suboptimal, whereas *Stilles is not being asked about (nor does it work with *mit/ohne*). Neither of these might have the right ring to it, as a matter of subjectivity, so I'm adding another one.

Comment: While I appreciate your adding "mit oder ohne" - now any answer option in my mind is covered. I'd like to insist that your mentioned trend is unexplained/left open for further questionmarks. So I'd rather write it differently to point out "there seems to be a trend to call it ...". And I'd appreciate to read it the other way round about "Stilles" - that this is the version without CO2 and due to ... "kein Stilles" is suboptimal to express "mit". Your answer, you decision.

Comment: Ii'm really just referring to an exchange I had with an immigrant the other day.

Comment: "*Gas* is outright wrong" - that depends on where you are. [In Switzerland, this is completely standard.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22wasser+mit+gas%22+site%3Ach&t=ffsb&ia=web)

Answer (score 4):

For the least troublesome experience, I would simply go with "Mineralwasser". You are -- rough guess -- about 50% likely to *either* be asked "mit oder ohne Kohlensäure?", *or* by default just given sparkling water.

If asked "mit oder ohne", tell them "mit". Done.

There is an additional thing to watch out for, which is Tafelwasser. No, Tafelwasser is not tap water in a caraffe, as you would expect e.g. in France. If only it was! It is not particularly exquisite water either, as the word "Tafel" (which is a more courtly version of "table") would suggest.
Tafelwasser is the same as Mineralwasser (and costs similar) except for the tiny detail that Mineralwasser has a rather low minimun quality standard (indeed worse than tap water), and Tafelwasser has *next to no quality standard at all*. Tafelwasser is the worst, most inferior thing that you are legally allowed fill in bottles and sell -- way too expensive -- with the designation "for human consumption". While there may exist some Tafelwasser which is actually drinkable, I'd personally rather drink from the tap.

There's **a lot** of other words that one could use instead of Mineralwasser, but not all are easy to pronounce, understood everywhere, or rather colloquial, or trouble-free otherwise.
For example, Selters is normally understood just fine (if for no other reason because of "Sekt oder Selters") but technically it's a brand name like Tempo or Jaccuzi. While "Gib mir ein Tempo" will -- almost guaranteed -- never be a source of discussion with anyone, ordering Selters in a Restaurant may very well get you "Wir haben nur Appolinaris/Adelholzner/Wasauchimmer". So, rather than sitting there and wondering what the hell an Adelholzner (what kind of wood? I wanted water...) may be, you might as well just say Mineralwasser.
Or, say, Bizzelwasser? Well, it should be Bitzelwasser in the first place, again, Bizzel is a (deliberately misspelled) brandname. But ordering a Bizzelwasser kinda makes you sound like a 5 year old (or a 75 year old talking to a 5 year old). Sure, you will likely still get what you want, only just it may not deliver the exact impression that you want.
Sprudel? I'm guessing you will be OK with that in Bavaria (that is indeed the *only* word for Mineralwasser that my grandmother knows). Somewhere in the north? They'll probably still understand, but... not sure. 40 years ago, I got puzzled looks when I used the only word that I knew for *that thing*. Might have changed. Things do change. Sometimes.

Now, Wasser mit Gas is... just... weird. Don't say that, it's not German (not in a de-DE way, anyway). Not sure where this comes from, maybe Austria? They seem to have a lot of funny words like that. Schlagoberst? No soldiers will be beaten. Verlängerter? It's not as obscene a thing as you might think. Palatschinken? No ham involved, sorry. Doppler? Would you be surprised if that referred to a a bottle?

Comment: no we don't say *mit Gas* either. That's Switzerland. Schlagoberst (very funny...), is actually *Schlagobers*, whipped cream.

Comment: Nice answer. @dlatikay Maybe the French "eau gazeuse" / "adjonction de gaz carbonique" makes some more people say "mit Gas" in Switzerland, more than OP observes in Germany. But that is just the same roman "con gaz" spill-over, and a bit weird. As a Swiss I am relieved to see that these "Real German" words like Sprudel and Selters (USA: Seltzers!) are not an easy solution.

Comment: LOL the way you hit the sack (South-eastern German:-)  and mean the donkey ("mit Gas").

Comment: "Bitzelwasser" - also spelled "Bizzelwasser" - is a popular [Hessian word](http://rmt-magazin.de/vermischtes/portrait/486-vor-125-jahren-wurde-der-frankfurter-kaufmann-adam-joest-geboren-erinnerungen-an-das-qjoest-huettchenq.html) for sparkling water. The word has been existing long before the brand "Bizzl" appeared. The company's seat is in Bad Vilbel, Hesse, and this explains the naming. But I guess outside of Hesse only few people would understand "Bitzelwasser".

Comment: ["Selterswasser"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selterswasser) is imo a border case. It means that it is water from the village Selters (Hesse), but you are right, it also was a brand name. But imo it became a popular synonym for [sparkling water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selters): *The words "Selters", "Selterwasser" or "Selter" have become synonyms for all kinds and brands of mineral water primarily in north and eastern Germany.*

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be universally understood, I believe you have to go with «Mineralwasser mit Kohlensäure».

A nice overview of regional variation, including several ones not mentioned here so far, can be found at [Die Getränke-Studie: Teil 2 – Kohlensäurehaltiges Mineralwasser](https://kristianmitk.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/die-getranke-studie-teil-2-kohlensaurehaltiges-mineralwasser/) on Kristian Baltruweit’s blog “Mapes Colorides”. He made a proper online survey in the style of the [Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) and has evaluated 1523 answers.

Here is Baltruweit’s overview map, but his discussion of the results is definitly worth reading (and so are his results for [Zitronenlimonade](https://kristianmitk.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/die-getranke-studie-teil-3-zitronenlimonade/), [Cola-Orangenlimonade-Mischung](https://kristianmitk.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/die-getrankestudie-teil-4-cola-orangenlimonade-mischung/), and [Bier-Limonade-Mischung](https://kristianmitk.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/die-getrankestudie-teil-5-bier-limonade-mischung/), and do not miss [Die Getränke-Studie: Teil 1 – Einführung](https://kristianmitk.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/die-getranke-studie-teil-1-einfuhrung/)):

[image: Wort 1: Kohlensäurehaltiges Mineralwasser]

Answer (score 3):

To add one observation:
*Mineralwasser* will get you a sparkling water in almost all cases, but some waiters will not double check with you and might give you a flat water. I suppose that this is a regional quirk. I'm from the western region but the waiter/waitress might be socialized anywhere, so I can only guess why *Mineralwasser* sometimes didn't give me the desired drink.

As this happened to me a few times (an avid sparkling water orderer who used to eat out in restaurants almost daily), I started using *Mineralwasser mit Sprudel* to emphasize that I desire sparkling water. The term however is a little clunky and not the norm and may sound awkward.

As always with choice of words, it depends on the occasion and speaker. Saying *Wasser mit Sprudel* is fine and pretty informal. If I was eating out in a formal setting, I would use *Wasser mit Kohlensäure*. Both terms will ensure that the waiting staff does not have to ask you whether you want gas or not. If you use *Mineralwasser*, there is a relatively small but real chance that you end up with a flat water or that you have to go through the minor ordeal of clarification (At least in the west and the north). Since I want to avoid that, I do not use *Mineralwasser* without adding *mit Sprudel* anymore.

Do not say *mit Gas*. It is not used in Germany. It's a one-to-one translation from romance languages. It will most likely be understood, especially in restaurants but it is not the correct term and will at best sound weird.

Comment: there is also gazowany und niegazowany in polish, used as an adjective to the noun - and used alone with the question: gazowany i niegazowany?

Comment: Ah thanks for that info! I only knew it from the romance languages.

Comment: "Do not say mit Gas. It is not used in Germany." But definitely used in Switzerland, where the automatic reaction to "Mineralwasser" is quite often "Mit or ohne Gas"? Though of course it may depend on which part of Switzerland...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to be understood you might also say

- *(Wasser) mit Zisch*
- *Kribbelwasser*
- *Brizzelwasser*
- *nervöses Wasser*
- *bitte (in) sprudelig*

and so on. Those words are more or less figurative, and any good German speaker should understand them. (Sorry to say that the service personnel in restaurants and bars quite often are not good German speakers.) Those expressions are not really colloquial in the sense of 'widely used', but one can come across them from time to time.

Once upon a time there was a [long discussion](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idForum=4&idThread=706823&lp=ende&lang=de) about it on dict.leo.org. There you can learn details from different regional expressions for 'Mineralwasser mit'.

Comment: What about *Blubberwasser*?

Comment: I don't think this is good advice for non-natives. Listeners unconsciously attune their linguistic expectation to the language variant used by the speaker. This means if a native speaker orders a _Brizzelwasser_, they will infer that the speaker knows the word, that it's an existing word, and that it's appropriate to use the word in a restaurant context, which helps to narrow down the meaning to "water with gas". If a non-native speaker uses the same word, they can't make the same inference as easily, and are likely to ask a clarifying question – which is exactly what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Im Hessischen - besonders im Raum Frankfurt - ist auch "Bitzelwasser" geläufig. Vgl. https://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/browse/pageSize/30/page/342/rsq//sn/hnwb und https://www.erlebnisraum-frankfurt.de/kunst-kultur/sehenswuerdigkeiten/501-die-frankfurter-wasserhaeuschen.html.

Answer (score 1):

As different dialects abound in Germany (making communications difficult) as as they tend to often be quite different form one-another the first advice would be to stick to Hochdeutsch. There it becomes a matter then of saying "Ich möchte bitte Sprudelwasser". You might also just ask for water "Ich möchte bitte Wasser" and might then be asked "mit oder ohne Sprudel" (with or without bubbles) to which you would reply "mit" (with).

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody mentioned it yet: If you only care about the *carbonated* part and not about the *mineral* part (i.e., if carbonated tap water is fine for you), you can just order [**Sodawasser**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodawasser).

If carbonated tap water is not available for some reason, the waiter will usually suggest carbonated mineral water instead, and you only have to agree.

---

Note: [Duden describes Sodawasser](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sodawasser) as "mit Kohlensäure versetztes Mineralwasser", but, in my personal experience (Austria), restaurants make a difference between Sodawasser (carbonated tap water) and Mineralwasser (bottled mineral water).

Answer (score 1):

You just order "ein Wasser".  That's sparkling by default, though you may get the question "mit oder ohne Kohlensäure?" to which you reply "mit, bitte".  The definite article is important: just asking for "Wasser" means potable water rather than an orderable item.  While it would be rather unusual in Germany to get that (you'd never get it without the server making sure that you indeed mean "Leitungswasser"), the definite article makes clear that you order a regular beverage.

So don't leave off "ein" in "Kann ich ein Wasser dazu bekommen?" oder "Ich hätte gerne ein Wasser."

Answer (score 0):

Sparkling water is called "Wasser mit Gas", or "Wasser mit Kohlensäure". For normal water one says "stilles Wasser" whereby one could also say "unruhiges Wasser" for sparkling water, but nobody say this!

So I would use "**Wasser mit Kohlensäure**" for sparkling water in German.

Comment: Do you think it is useful to restructure your answer a bit to clarify what is common and what would be logical yet is uncommon? I'd say your answer contains what I would answer (despite "mit Gas"). I just find it a bit hard to differentiate and make right reference.

Comment: okei, but I have clearly written what I would recommend (Wasser mit Kohlensäure) and have listed different options (for normal water and sparkling water), so I don't know what your problem is ...

Comment: My suggestion: 

> Sparkling water  is called `Wasser mit Gas` or `Wasser mit Kohlensäure`. For normal water one says `stilles Wasser`.

So I would use `**Wasser mit Kohlensäure**` for sparkling water in German.

Whereby it looks logical one could also say `unruhiges Wasser` for sparkling water - but nobody says this!
<
(Here my question stays: you mention two wordings just would use only one - what happens to "mit Gas" for usage? And I left your wording as close as possible, it is your answer. I see mixture of how to call, what to use, the range and the impossibilities)

Comment: Nobody in his right mind says *Wasser mit Gas*. Or, if somebody uses it, then just by using a term heared somewhere during holidays in a foreign country where a waiter asked "With gas?". It is however not (yet?) the proper way of expression in German.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I generally use **Sprudelwasser** for *sparkling water*, that is not a way to order it at a restaurant, though.

Comment: "Wasser mit Kohlensäure" könnte sich auch auf mit Kohlensäure versetztes Leitungswasser beziehen, wie es sich viele mit den entsprechenden Geräten und Kartuschen heute selbst machen.

Comment: @Chieron: yeah, sure you can. I don't see the term "Sprudelwasser" mentioned or questioned in this answer.

Comment: Wasser mit gas, if I remember correctly (could be wrong), I ordered *mineral wasser* on swiss air flight (so could be a difference in dialects), and the stewardess asked *mit gas?* So could be that the flight attendant was not native German speaker).

Comment: I should add to my "nobody in his right mind": that's for the regions of Germanistan I am familiar with. There are some indications that possibly people in Switzerland use this indeed. Cheers to Switzerland!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

> Wasser mit Kohlensäure

At least in Germany this will be understood everywhere.

Comment: This has been said a hundret times now and does not add anything new.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich it hasn't been said in one or two sentences. That's new